# Add Future dates for missing Rows in a Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How to impute the Missed dates with next Dates in a data frame?

```
wtg_at1.tail(10)
```

|  | AmbientTemperatue | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 818 | 31.237499 | 2020-03-28 |
| 819 | 32.865974 | 2020-03-29 |
| 820 | 32.032558 | 2020-03-30 |
| 821 | 31.671166 | NaN |
| 822 | 31.389927 | NaN |
| 823 | 31.243660 | NaN |
| 824 | 31.206777 | NaN |
| 825 | 31.241503 | NaN |
| 826 | 31.309531 | NaN |
| 827 | 31.382531 | NaN |

I am expecting my output data frame something similar to below. After 30th March, I am expecting next dates from 31st March.

|  | AmbientTemperatue | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 818 | 31.237499 | 2020-03-28 |
| 819 | 32.865974 | 2020-03-29 |
| 820 | 32.032558 | 2020-03-30 |
| 821 | 31.671166 | 2020-03-31 |
| 822 | 31.389927 | 2020-04-01 |
| 823 | 31.243660 | 2020-04-02 |
| 824 | 31.206777 | 2020-04-03 |
| 825 | 31.241503 | 2020-04-04 |
| 826 | 31.309531 | 2020-04-05 |
| 827 | 31.382531 | 2020-04-06 |

I tried below code but not giving desired output.

```
wtg_at1.append(pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range(start=wtg_at1.Date.iloc[-8], periods=7, freq='D', closed='right')}))
wtg_at1
```

|  | AmbientTemperatue | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 32.032558 | 2017-12-31 |
| 1 | 26.667757 | 2018-01-01 |
| 2 | 25.655754 | 2018-01-02 |
| 3 | 25.514013 | 2018-01-03 |
| 4 | 24.927652 | 2018-01-04 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 823 | 31.243660 | NaN |
| 824 | 31.206777 | NaN |
| 825 | 31.241503 | NaN |
| 826 | 31.309531 | NaN |
| 827 | 31.382531 | NaN |

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one group of missing values is possible forward filling them and add counter by cumulative sum converted to days timedeltas:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['Date'] = df['Date'].ffill() + pd.to_timedelta(df['Date'].isna().cumsum(), unit='d')
print (df)
     AmbientTemperatue       Date
818          31.237499 2020-03-28
819          32.865974 2020-03-29
820          32.032558 2020-03-30
821          31.671166 2020-03-31
822          31.389927 2020-04-01
823          31.243660 2020-04-02
824          31.206777 2020-04-03
825          31.241503 2020-04-04
826          31.309531 2020-04-05
827          31.382531 2020-04-06
```

Another possible idea is reassign values by minimal datetime and length of `DataFrame`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.date_range(df['Date'].min(), periods=len(df))
```

---

If there is multiple groups with missing values:

```
print (df)
     AmbientTemperatue        Date
818          31.237499  2020-03-28
819          32.865974  2020-03-29
820          32.032558  2020-03-30
821          31.671166         NaN
822          31.389927         NaN
823          31.243660         NaN
824          31.206777  2020-05-08
825          31.241503         NaN
826          31.309531         NaN
827          31.382531         NaN

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

m = df['Date'].notna()
s = (~m).groupby(m.cumsum()).cumsum()
df['Date'] = df['Date'].ffill() + pd.to_timedelta(s, unit='d')
print (df)
    AmbientTemperatue       Date
818          31.237499 2020-03-28
819          32.865974 2020-03-29
820          32.032558 2020-03-30
821          31.671166 2020-03-31
822          31.389927 2020-04-01
823          31.243660 2020-04-02
824          31.206777 2020-05-08
825          31.241503 2020-05-09
826          31.309531 2020-05-10
827          31.382531 2020-05-11
```